# What changes have to be made in X code project when it’s needed to be opened in another Mac with different developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been working on a project at my workplace and before holiday, I’ve e-mailed the files  (entire folder as zip) I’ve worked so far, so that I can open and work on it from home.

But I’m getting error when trying to run the project. It says main. Storyboard and launchscreen not found, but they are available in project .

Answer (score 1):

> I’ve e-mailed the files I’ve worked so far, so that I can open and work on it from home

No, you cannot email files selectively. All contents of a project are needed. You zip the entire project folder and email that. Or, push the whole project to github and clone it to your other computer when you get home.

Comment: Hi, ive mailed entire project folder as zip and downloaded at home . Still getting the error

Comment: Well, if the storyboards are showing in red, you can drag them into the project navigator to show the project where they are now.

Comment: It’s not showing In red . When I run the project it says Build input file cannot be found launchscreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard

Comment: You could still try it. Dragging a file into the project navigator is how you show the project where it is. I assure you that this should work; I work on the same projects from different computers all the time.